# How to remove a row value that appears in all rows using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
| column1 |
|---------|
| [b,e,c] |
| [e,a,c] |
| [a,b,c] |
```

Since the last value is the same on all rows of the column, I want to get rid of it to obtain this:

```
| column1 |
|---------|
| [b,e] |
| [e,a] |
| [a,b] |
```

Note: This will only eliminate the item if they appear at the end of lists in all rows

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: is this a list in a series? do you mind sharing the source code? ``df.to_dict('records')``

Answer (score 1):

You could transform that data to a dataframe, and then check if all values are equal (which is different than checking for duplicates):

```
>>> x = df['column1'].apply(pd.Series)
>>> x
   0  1  2
0  b  e  c
1  e  a  c
2  a  b  c
>>> x.eq(x.loc[0]).all()
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Then we can remove those columns, and `stack` + `agg` to get back to the initial format:

```
>>> x.loc[:,x.ne(x.loc[0]).any()]
   0  1
0  b  e
1  e  a
2  a  b
>>> x.loc[:,x.ne(x.loc[0]).any()].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
0    [b, e]
1    [e, a]
2    [a, b]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Something below.

```
>>> df['column1'] = df.column1.str.extract(r'(\w,\w)')
>>> df
  column1
0     b,e
1     e,a
2     a,b
```

Or with replace for the particular example you posted..

```
>>> df.column1.str.replace(',c','')
0    [b,e]
1    [e,a]
2    [a,b]
```

Answer (score 0):

If above column has python list and not the string representation of list, apply `pd.Series` on the column, then create the masking for `duplicated` and assign  None if `True` else assign the series, and drop `None` on `axis=1`, then pass `list`, and `axis=1` to `agg`:

```py
(df['column1']
.apply(pd.Series)
.apply(lambda x: None if x.duplicated(keep=False).any() 
                    else x).dropna(axis=1).agg(list, axis=1))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
0    [b, e]
1    [e, a]
2    [a, b]
dtype: object
```

If the column values are string instead of list, then first convert it to list before executing above code by `df['column1'] = df['column1'].str[1:-1].str.split(',')`

Comment: This gives me ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series

Comment: @biopython, then the values in `column1` are probably string, please convert it to list first. I have already added that note in the answer and the way you can convert it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `set.intersection` with `explode`:

```
s = pd.Series([[*"bec"], [*"eac"], [*"abc"]], name="column1")
common = set.intersection(*s.apply(set))

s = s.explode()
s2 = s[~s.isin(common)]
s2.groupby(s2.index).apply(list)
```

Output:

```
0    [b, e]
1    [e, a]
2    [a, b]
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

If you don't care about duplicates and order, you can make it simpler:

```
s1 = s.apply(set)
s1 - set.intersection(*s1)
```

Output:

```
0    {e, b}
1    {a, e}
2    {a, b}
Name: column1, dtype: object
```